# How can I approximate function parameters given data from the function curves?

Tags: functions, optimization, sampling, data-analysis

So say I have some function $f(x)$. This function is of some extended form that includes four-constant parameters $a,b,c,d$, creating $f(a,b,c,d,x)$. I now have curves of data for different values of $d$ along the $x$-axis. Now I need to approximate $a,b,c$ using the different curves of $d$ values.

Is there an optimization algorithm that can be used to find the best fit for $a,b,c$ that fit the function data?

Comment: Least squares method minimizes root mean square errors during a  curve fit.

Comment: @wjmccann : you wrote : I have some function $f(x)$. So, you can tell us what is the function $f(x)$. As far I understand your question, the problem is to compute approximate values of the parameters included in the known function.